# Why isn't System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders indexable?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

To retrieve header values from a `HttpHeaders` (or `HttpResponseHeaders` in my case) instance, I have to call `GetValues` e.g. `response.Headers.GetValues("Content-Length")`. This is inconvenient.

It seems like it would be straight-forward to support something like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> this[string headerName]
{
    return GetValues(GetHeaderDescriptor(headerName));
}
```

Is there a reason why `HttpHeaders` doesn't support this to enable the much less cumbersome `response.Headers["Content-Length"]`?

Comment: Asp.Net Core does this properly with its IHeaderDictionary, I don't understand what the problem is with HttpClient's header type.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because _"[your question is just a rant in disguise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"_

Comment: I don't disagree @MickyD - if there's no technical reason this wouldn't work, let's close this (perhaps in favour of a PR to the relevant class!)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a straight-forward way of getting header values, you can use Http-specific implementations like HttpWebRequest and [HttpWebResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse?view=netframework-4.8).

Example:

```
        var testRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        var testResponse = (HttpWebResponse)testRequest.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(testResponse.Headers["Content-Length"]);
```

Comment: Upvoted because it's great to see HttpWebResponse supports this, but I understand HttpClient to be the successor/more modern approach for doing HTTP requests so it's not ideal to have to go back to doing it like this